# how select the right element to apply CSS (SASS to be exact) to

Tags: html, css, reactjs, twitter-bootstrap, sass

I have the current alignment when i inspect the **elements** in my current page.

```
html body #root div div div div div div div div div.section-wrapper div.section-content table.selection tbody tr td span span.validate-check
```

when i click on the last one, the one i intend to apply **scss** to `span.validate-check`

This is the little message on the right side of `inspect` screen

```
*, *::before, *::after {
    box-sizing: inherit;
}
```

I am still unable to access the element via the combination below:

```
.selection{
   ...
   tbody{
     tr{
       td{
          >span{
           background-color: red;             < === this works apply the color
           .span.validate-check {
             color: blue                      < this is what i want but not working
          }               
        }
       }
     }
   }
 }
}
```

I would appreciate any suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the selector is wrong

```css
.selection{
   ...
   tbody{
     tr{
       td{
          >span{
           background-color: red;             < === this works apply the color
            .validate-check {
             color: blue;                      < remove the .span just use the class name
          }               
        }
       }
     }
   }
 }
}
```

## also check the semicolon

Answer (score 0):

Remove the . before span in .span.validate-check

```
.selection{
   ...
   tbody{
     tr{
       td{
          >span{
           background-color: red;          
           span.validate-check {
             color: blue                      
          }               
        }
       }
     }
   }
 }
}
```